# On Ruby-on-Rails it's possible to pass variables from controller to view through respond_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, respond-to

I want to submit a message and after that to show a message and open a popup window. The message is saved properly on DataBase, but the message don't show up , instead I receive this

```
NoMethodError in Private::Conversations#create
Showing /var/www/appror/app/views/private/conversations/_open.js.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`
```

The application run on

```
Rails version             5.2.2;
Ruby version              2.5.3-p105 (x86_64-linux);
RubyGems version          2.7.6;
Rack version              2.0.6
```

after the message is save, in controller

```
/app/channels/private/conversation_channel.rb

class Private::ConversationsController < ApplicationController    
    def create
        recipient_id = Post.find(params[:post_id]).user.id
        conversation = Private::Conversation.new(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: recipient_id)
        if conversation.save

            respond_to do |format|
                format.js {render partial: 'posts/show/contact_user/message_form/success'}
        end
....
end
```

from

```
/app/views/posts/show/contact_user/message_form/_success.js.erb
```

where it's

```
<%= render 'private/conversations/open' %>
```

it should show the message

```
/app/views/private/conversations/_open.js.erb
```

where

```
var conversation = $('body').find("[data-pconversation-id='" + 
                            "<%= @conversation.id %>" + 
                            "']");
```

Normally it should go forward and show the message and popup, but instead I'm receiving

```
NoMethodError in Private::Conversations#create
Showing /var/www/appror/app/views/private/conversations/_open.js.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass`
```

After debugging I saw that <%= @conversation %> is empty... so, it makes sense the error. But how I can pass @conversatio from controller to view ? It's possible to pass this using

```
respond_to do |format| format.js
```

?

Thank you!

EDIT:

thank you @max, indeed `@conversation = ....` solved the issue

Comment: `conversation = Private::Conversation.new(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: recipient_id)` creates a local variable that is only available in the `create` method. If you want to assign an instance variable you need to use the  `@conversation = ...`. You can also pass variables to the view by using [locals](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables). Rendering a partial from the controller is highly unconventional and quite questionable from a code organization / maintenance perspective.

Comment: Partials are meant to share code between views. Not to be resuable views.

Comment: @max you said: `Rendering a partial from the controller is highly unconventional and quite questionable from a code organization / maintenance perspective` can you please let me know why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an @ in your conversation variable in your controller, and your variable is falling out of scope. 
`@conversation = Private::Conversation.new(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: recipient_id`